# Behaviour of greater than (and equivalent) for Option

Tags: f#, comparison, option-type

I'm working on something for an image processing task (it's not greatly relevant here), and I stumbled across behaviour of F#'s Option type that surprised me, regarding performing greater than (>) comparisons.  I couldn't find anything that directly explained what I should expect (more on that below) on Stack Overflow, the F# docs or the wider web.

The specific part I am looking at looks something like:

```
let sort3Elems (arr: byte option []) = 
    if arr.[0] > arr.[1] then swap &arr.[0] &arr.[1]
    if arr.[1] > arr.[2] then swap &arr.[1] &arr.[2]
    if arr.[0] > arr.[1] then swap &arr.[0] &arr.[2]
```

where I will be passing in arrays of four byte options (if you're wondering why this looks weird and is super-unfunctional, right now I'm deliberately trying to re-implement the non-functional-language implementation of an algorithm in a textbook).  I was expecting this to cause a compiler error, where it would complain that the options couldn't be directly compared.  To my surprise, this compiled fine.  Intrigued, I tested it out in F# Interactive, the results of which look something like the below:

```
let arr: byte option [] = Array.zeroCreate 4;;
val arr : byte option [] = [|None; None; None; None|]

> arr.[0] <- Some(127uy);;
val it : unit = ()

> arr.[2] <- Some(55uy);;
val it : unit = ()

> arr.[0] > arr.[2];;
val it : bool = true

> arr.[0] < arr.[2];;
val it : bool = false

> arr.[0] < arr.[1];;
val it : bool = false

> arr.[0] > arr.[1];;
val it : bool = true

> arr.[2] > arr.[1];;
val it : bool = true

> arr.[3] > arr.[1];;
val it : bool = false

> arr.[3] < arr.[1];;
val it : bool = false

> arr.[3] > arr.[1];;
val it : bool = false
```

It seems to me that essentially the comparison operators must always return true (false) when asking whether a Some is greater (less) than a None, two Nones always return false, and two Somes of the same contained type compare the contained values (assuming that they can be compared I imagine).  This makes sense, though I was surprised.

Wanting to confirm this, I attempted to track something down that would explain the behaviour I should expect, but I couldn't find anything that addressed the point.  The [Option page in the MS F# Guide docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/options) doesn't make any mention of it, and I couldn't find anything in places like F# for fun and profit.  I couldn't even manage to find a page about Option anywhere in the MS API docs...  Looking at [the source for Option in the F# GitHub repo](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/option.fs) doesn't tell me anything. The best I could find was [a blog post by Don Syme](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsyme/2009/11/08/equality-and-comparison-constraints-in-f/) from years ago, which didn't actually answer my question.  There were a smattering of Stack Overflow questions that discussed topics to do with the comparison operators or Option types, but I didn't find anything that dealt with the combination of the two.

So, my question is, does performing greater than/less than comparisons on the Option type return the results I have speculated about above?  I'm guessing that this is reasonably common knowledge amongst F# programmers, but it was news to me.  As a sub-/related question, does anyone know where I could/should have looked to for more information?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The F# compiler automatically generates comparison for discriminated unions and record types. Since option is just a discriminated union, this also means that you get an automatic comparison for unions. I'm not sure if there is a good web page documenting this, but you can find a description in [section 8.15.4 in the F# specification](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf):

> #### 8.15.4 Behavior of the Generated CompareTo Implementations
>
> For a type T, the behavior of the generated System.IComparable.CompareTo implementation is as
>   follows:
>
> - Convert the y argument to type T . If the conversion fails, raise the InvalidCastException.
> - If T is a reference type and y is null, return 1.
> - If T is a struct or record type, invoke FSharp.Core.Operators.compare on each corresponding pair
>     of fields of x and y in declaration order, and return the first non-zero result.
> - If T is a union type, invoke FSharp.Core.Operators.compare first on the index of the union cases
>     for the two values, and then on each corresponding field pair of x and y for the data carried by
>     the union case. Return the first non-zero result.

As documented in the last case, the case for option first compares the cases. `None` has an index smaller than `Some` so a `None` value will always be smaller than any `Some` value. If the cases match, then `None = None` and `Some n` with `Some m` are compared based on `n` and `m`.

Comment: Wow, an answer from _the_ Tomas Petricek.  I really should have thought of looking at the specification.  Thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: @Jarak - Honestly, I only thought about looking at the specification myself after I failed to find a good reference about this on the web :-)