# Implementing F# comparison on disciminated unions

Tags: f#, comparison-operators

I have a type for logging levels:

```
type LoggingLevel =
| Trace
| Debug
| Info
```

I would like to say that some logging levels are higher than others. For example, `Trace` is higher than `Info`.

So I implemented `IComparable` like this:

```
[<StructuralEqualityAttribute>]
[<CustomComparisonAttribute>]
type LoggingLevel =
| Trace
| Debug
| Info

  interface IComparable<LoggingLevel> with
    override this.CompareTo other =
      let score x =
        match x with
        | Trace -> 0
        | Debug -> 1
        | Info -> 2
      (score this) - (score other)
```

But when I try to use it, I get an error:

```
if a >= b 
then 
  // ...
```

> The type 'LoggingLevel' does not support the 'comparison' constraint. For example, it does not support the 'System.IComparable' interface

How have I gone wrong here?

---

I managed to get it working, but now the type definition is so verbose! There must be a better way...

```
[<CustomEquality>]
[<CustomComparisonAttribute>]
type LoggingLevel =
  | Trace
  | Debug
  | Info

  override this.Equals (obj) =
    match obj with
    | :? LoggingLevel as other ->
      match (this, other) with
      | (Trace, Trace) -> true
      | (Debug, Debug) -> true
      | (Info, Info) -> true
      | _ -> false
    | _ -> false

  override this.GetHashCode () =
    match this with
    | Trace -> 0
    | Debug -> 1
    | Info -> 2

  interface IComparable<LoggingLevel> with
    member this.CompareTo (other : LoggingLevel) =
      let score x =
        match x with
        | Trace -> 0
        | Debug -> 1
        | Info -> 2
      (score this) - (score other)

  interface IComparable with
    override this.CompareTo other =
      (this :> IComparable<LoggingLevel>).CompareTo (other :?> LoggingLevel)
```

Comment: Can you hover over the definition of your LoggingLevel to verify that it indeed has registered the method and it is returning an [`Int32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1.compareto?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IComparable_1_CompareTo__0_)?

Comment: If I hover over (using Ionide) I do not see a mention of `IComparable`

Comment: `this.CompareTo` is `LoggingLevel -> int`

Comment: I think it is complaining about ``IComparable`` the non-generic interface here. Try adding: ``interface IComparable with override this.CompareTo other = (this :?> IComparable<LoggingLevel>).CompareTo other``

Comment: @dumetrulo `interface IComparable with    override this.CompareTo other =      (this :> IComparable<LoggingLevel>).CompareTo (other :?> LoggingLevel)` will make it compile, but is this really the best way?

Comment: Can you share an example, excluding all of the custom equality stuff, of the type definition and actual example usage. I do think a `match` expression could help you avoid all of this.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think you actually need to implement anything to get Discriminated Union comparisons.  I say this based on Tomas P's answer to [this question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52220189/6792709).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to say that some logging levels are higher than others. For example, `Trace` is higher than `Info`.

Do you need to use custom equality and custom comparison at all? F# has these built in for Discriminated Unions. You just need to write them in increasing order in the type definition:

```
type LoggingLevel =
  | Info
  | Debug
  | Trace // Note the order here! 

Trace > Info // true

let levels = [ Trace; Debug; Info; Trace; Debug; Info ]

levels |> List.sort
// [Info; Info; Debug; Debug; Trace; Trace]
// Comparison ✔

levels |> List.countBy id
// [(Trace, 2); (Debug, 2); (Info, 2)]
// Equality ✔
```

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52220335/1256041

Comment: That is... so much better. I was not aware that comparisons were implemented for DUs automatically.

Comment: @sdgfsdh Frankly, the free equality should be expected. I think object reference equality (e.g. in normal classes) is a really bad default. The free comparison though, is a nice bonus in general, and essential in F# where set items and map keys have to be comparable because of how those immutable data structures are implemented.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're comparison implementation is off here based on the typing. The following compiles for me:

```
[<CustomComparison>]
[<StructuralEquality>]
type LoggingLevel =
| Trace
| Debug
| Info

    interface System.IComparable with 
        member this.CompareTo other = 
            0
            // replace 0 with your comparison logic here

let a = Trace
let b = Debug

if Trace > Debug then printfn "here"
```

Note that `other` in this case will be of type `obj` and you'll need to box accordingly. Made all the trickier by the fact that all cases here are empty (i.e. lacking type)

I would be curious to see a more complete example, of you attempting to use this logic. I suspect a `match` expression might be better and allow you to remove this custom comparison.

That said, without knowing your exact use case, wouldn't something like this be more functional (and perhaps) simpler?

```
type LoggingLevel = Trace | Debug | Info

module Logger =        
    let doSomeLogging logLevel =
        match logLevel with
        | Trace -> "trace"
        | Debug -> "debug"
        | Info -> "info"

let result = Logger.doSomeLogging Trace
```

Comment: I think this solution requires you to implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: It's not required. But you will get a compiler warning.

Comment: Isn't the warning there for a reason though?

Comment: Yes. It's generally good not to ignore them. But in this case it isn't affecting your issue.